# How to fetch my followers Instagram Activity via API?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

My scenario is, basically, as an Instagram user I want to fetch my following users activities through API, a list of their likes, comments etc. It is able via user interface but instead I want to fetch them. 
No programming language enforcement. Nodejs, Python preferably.

Thanks for any of your helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, kinda found a way to solve. There're bunch of API's on github called Instagram Private Api. I go with python one which gives a horrible response.